# Why is Quicksort using Dutch National Flag partition technique working slower than a normal Quicksort?

Tags: c++, quicksort

My implementation for Quicksort using Dutch National Flag partition technique.
http://ideone.com/WgAiGG

And for a normal Quicksort.
http://ideone.com/GOE5Jl

The code for Quicksort using Dutch National Flag partition technique

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

void partition (int *a, int s, int e, int &start, int &end)
{
     start=s-1; 
     int mid=s;
     end=e;

     int pivot=a[e],temp,i;

     while (mid < end)
     {
           if  (a[mid] < pivot)
           {
               temp = a[start+1];
               a[start+1] = a[mid];
               a[mid] = temp;
               start++;
               mid++;     
           }
           else if (a[mid] == pivot)
           {
                mid++;
           }
           else
           {
               temp = a[end-1];
               a[end-1] = a[mid];
               a[mid] = temp;
               end--;
           }
     }
     temp = a[mid];
     a[mid] = a[e];
     a[e] = temp;
     cout<<start<<" "<<end<<"\n";
}

void Qsort(int *a, int s, int e)
{
     if (s>=e)
        return;
     int start,end;
     partition(a,s,e,start,end);
     Qsort(a,s,start);
     Qsort(a,end+1,e);
}

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int i,j;
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        a[j] = rand()%40;
        cout<<a[j]<<" ";
    }
    clock_t start = clock();
    Qsort(a,0,n-1);

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<"\nTime elapsed: "<<((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;

}
```

The code for normal Quicksort

```
#include<iostream>

#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int partition (int *a, int s, int e)
{
    int i=s;
    int j=e-1;
    int pivot = a[e],temp;
    while (i<=j)
    {
          if  (a[i] < pivot)
          {
              i++;
              continue;
          }
          if  (a[j] > pivot)
          {
              j--;
              continue;
          }

          temp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = temp;
          i++;
          j--;
    }

    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[e];
    a[e] = temp;
    return i;
}


void qsort (int *a, int s, int e)
{
     if  (s>=e)
     {
         return;
     }
     int i = partition (a,s,e);
     qsort(a,s,i-1);
     qsort(a,i,e);
}


int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int i,j;
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        a[j] = rand()%40;
        cout<<a[j]<<" ";
    }
    clock_t start = clock();
    qsort(a,0,n-1);


    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<"\nTime elapsed: "<<((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;

}
```

Comment: These two implementations seem have similar time complexity, you may need to compare the running time for larger arrays, 100 elements is way too small to say something about it.

Comment: I tried doing it for an array of 1000 elements where the rand() function was generating values in between 0-39, and still the former was slower than latter.

Comment: Are you sure both arrays process exactly the same sequence of numbers?

Comment: They do not. But I have tried number of times and never have I found Dutch partitioning Quicksort faster than the normal Quicksort.

Comment: You have to feed both approaches with exactly same input array, then you can say that one is faster than the other. Since there are swap operations involved. Otherwise, the comparison is unfair.

Comment: I tried with 70 elements in the range 0-9 and still found normal Quicksort faster.

Comment: `1000` elements that are all `0`?  :)  Looking at the DNF implementation, it is a 3 way branch instead of a 2 way branch, and branch prediction failure is a serious performance problem.  DNF adds complexity and only improves performance when there are duplicates of the pivot, which even in your 0-9 case is going to be an uncommon case (1 in 10).

Comment: First, you should stop including the output time in your measurement. Then look at non-tiny arrays (i.e. tens of thousands, at least). Make the input deterministic and time several executions over the same data with *both* algorithms. You can use `srand(0)`, `srand(1)`, and so on to get the same "random" numbers over and over.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. But I think I figured out the issue. The problem was arising as there were some printing statements in the DNF implementation. Once I removed those, I could see a slight improvement in performance when I took 40000 elements in the range of 0-399.